# for loop in c is not incrementing on the final iteration of the loop

Tags: c, for-loop, increment

Hello and thank all who bothered to read. I am currently trying to execute a program in c that contains a function with this for loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int i, goal;
    char resp[1];

    printf("How many people would you like to ask?");
    scanf("%d" ,&goal);

    for(i = 0; i < goal; i++){
        printf("-Person %d: Would you like to register to vote?\n",(i+1));
        scanf("%s", resp);
        if((strcmp(resp, "n"))==0){
            printf("\nOk.\n");
        }
        else if((strcmp(resp, "y"))==0){
            printf("\nRegistering...\n");
        }
    }
    printf("\n%d people asked! Taking a break.\n", goal);
}
```

Yet for some reason, when I run the program, after pressing n for all of the runs, the for loop does not increment, leading to an infinite loop on the final run.
I have tried changing the for loop to a while loop with the same results and have also tried the y option for the last time which led to a whole host of other issues. In order to get the goal value I am using scanf though when I tried using fgets I still came into the same flawed result or worse. I ran this code into a debugger and when executing the program line by line it works fine, but running it normally seems to be the issue. Any help is appreciated and I am willing to clarify or expand on my code. This is my first post here so apologies if this has been asked 50 trillion times.

Comment: You need to post a [mcve]. You've left out the part of the code that has the problem.

Comment: - user3386109 the code above is the minimal reproducible example. Sorry for not making that clear.

Comment: The word "reproducible" means that I can copy, paste, compile and run the code, and **reproduce** the problem. The code you've posted is perfect example of code that's not a [mcve].

Comment: No, the code in the question is not a [mre]. Without `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <string.h>`, it won't compile. Without a `main` function, it won't run. We need something we can copy-and-paste and run for ourselves. You've omitted part of your program; we can't guess whether what you've omitted is relevant.

Comment: You're not showing how you declared i, resp and goal

Comment: let me guess, `char resp[1];` ?

Comment: this code it's not a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), since it does not lead to the error you say, the infinite loop does not occur when I implemented it in my way.

Comment: Alright, I edited my code and now it should be reproducible. I am sorry for the amount of groans, headshakes, and cringe I caused during this process. I am new to the site but that does not excuse my ignorance of the minimal reproducible example. I hope this makes up for it.

Comment: Change `char resp[1]` to `char resp[16]` and try again. A C string has a zero at the end known as a NUL terminator. So a string like "y" is actually two characters, the 'y' and the NUL terminator. And nothing stops the user from typing "yes", which requires an a array of at least 4 characters.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks for the help and I apologize for causing you so much trouble!

Comment: @Billthetaxationman No problem, live and learn :)

Comment: What @user3386109 says gets you over the hang. If you use scanf to read a string, and the user enters _one_ character, two chars are overwritten. With an array of size 16, you are still in trouble if the user enters 16 or more characters.